# How to escape Python Regex special characters without using backslash

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that looks something like this:

```
pattern = "".join([
     '^', 
     lbtests['lbname'], 
     '\d{4}',
     '[A-Za-z]{2},
     '$'
])

re.compile(pattern)
```

My problem is that the lbtests dictionary sometimes resolves to a string that contains parentheses, e.g. `Basophils (Abs)`, so the program thinks I'm trying to create a group.  Instead, I want it to match the string "Basophils (Abs)".

Is there a way to escape the parentheses without using backslashes?  If not, is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.escape(lbtests['lbname'])` to escape the string to match it exactly.

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> lbtests = {'lbname':'Basophils (Abs)'}
>>> re.escape(lbtests['lbname'])
'Basophils\\ \\(Abs\\)'
```

Note that it escapes the space as well as the parentheses, so it will match exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `re.escape`

```py
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pattern = f'hello {re.escape("(world)")}'
    print(re.match(pattern, 'hello (world)'))

    # output: 
    # <re.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='hello (world)'>
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape